# Javascript clock/time increment improvement

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I've create a time picker component and it works as it should. I've written it in vanilla js. I have learned js purely through writing jQuery and wanted to see if anyone would let me know how they would improved the code or just provide feedback.

Here is a working fiddle of the code > https://jsfiddle.net/mw6pujna/2/

The principle is that the user can select the hours (12 hour format) and minutes. The minutes go in 15 minute increments. On load the current time is set to the nearest 15 mins (in the future).

Here is the js with html underneath for reference:

JS:

```
const increment = document.getElementsByClassName('c-time-block__incrementer');
const hours = document.getElementById('hours');
const mins = document.getElementById('minutes');
const buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
const d = new Date();
let h = d.getHours() % 12;
let m = d.getMinutes();

// Set the initial time of the clock to the next 15 minute incrememt and handle hours.
const setInitialTime = (m, h) => {
    if (m > 45){
        m = '00'; 
        h = h + 1;
    } else if (m < 45) {
        m = Math.ceil(m / 15) * 15;
    }
    if(h === 0) {
        h = 12;
    }
    hours.innerHTML = pad(h);
    mins.innerHTML = pad(m);
}

setInitialTime(m,h);

// Check if am/pm and make relevant selector button active
const setInitialPeriod = (h) => {
    h < 12 ? buttons[0].classList.add('selected') : buttons[1].classList.add('selected');
}
setInitialPeriod(h);

// Add click events and pass the id to the counter object
for (let selector of increment) {
    selector.addEventListener('click', () => { 
        if (selector.id === 'hrs-inc' || selector.id === 'min-inc') {
            counter.inc(selector.id);
        } else if (selector.id === 'hrs-dec' || selector.id === 'min-dec') {
            counter.dec(selector.id);
        }

    });
}

// Counter object with the increment and decrement methods
const counter = {
    inc: function(id) {
        switch(id) {
            case 'hrs-inc':
                h = parseInt(hours.innerHTML) + 1;
                h = h % 12;
                if(h === 0) {
                    h = 12;
                }            
                hours.innerHTML = pad(h);
                break;

            case 'min-inc':
                m = parseInt(mins.innerHTML) + 15;
                if (m > 45){
                    m = 0;
                }
                mins.innerHTML = pad(m);
                break;
        }
    },
    dec: function(id) {
        switch(id) {
            case 'hrs-dec':
                h = h - 1;
                if(h < 1) {
                    h = 12;
                }            
                hours.innerHTML = pad(h);
                break;

            case 'min-dec':
                m = parseInt(mins.innerHTML) - 15;
                if (m < 0){
                    m = 45;
                }
                mins.innerHTML = pad(m);
                break;
        }
    },
};

// Padding function to add a leading zero
function pad(n) {
    return (n < 10 && n != "00" || n === 0) ? ("0" + n) : n;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="c-time-container">
<h1>Select installation time</h1>
<div class="c-time-component">  
    <div class="c-time-block">
        <div id="hrs-inc" class="c-time-block__incrementer">
            <img src="/assets/images/ic_up_arrow_white_64px.svg" alt="Time increment">
        </div>
        <div id="hours" class="c-time-block__number">
        00
        </div>
        <div id="hrs-dec" class="c-time-block__incrementer">
            <img src="/assets/images/ic_down_arrow_white_64px.svg" alt="Time increment">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="c-time-block c-time-block--separator">:</div>

    <div class="c-time-block">
        <div id="min-inc" class="c-time-block__incrementer">
            <img src="/assets/images/ic_up_arrow_white_64px.svg" alt="Time increment">
        </div>
        <div id="minutes" class="c-time-block__number">
        00
        </div>
        <div id="min-dec" class="c-time-block__incrementer">
            <img src="/assets/images/ic_down_arrow_white_64px.svg" alt="Time increment">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="c-time-block c-time-block--selector">
        <button class="btn c-time-btn">am</button>
        <button class="btn c-time-btn">pm</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This might fit better on CodeReview. If i would write it, i would seperate the logic and the selectors, so that you got a generic Clock function which you pass the dom elements in

Comment: Ok thanks for that. I'll take a look at code review.